# ¿Tiene o ha tenido el verbo "ser" participio de presente?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, conjugación, cópulas, participio

El antiguo [participio de presente](https://www.delcastellano.com/participio-presente-activo-espanol/), que se diferencia del de pasado en que hace referencia a un sujeto activo más que a uno pasivo (*amante* el que ama activamente, *amado* el que recibe pasivamente el amor), sigue presente en nuestros días lexicalizado en otras categorías gramaticales. Así, además de la ya mencionada *amante*, tenemos *corriente*, *cantante*, *mediante* y muchas otras.

Incluso el propio verbo *estar* parece tener un participio de presente:

> **[estante](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GmQfK5v)**
>
> `De`*`estar`*`y`*`-nte;`*`lat.`*`stans, -antis`*.
>
> 3. adj. p. us. Que está presente o permanente en un lugar. *Pedro, estante en la corte romana.*

Pero ¿tiene o ha tenido el propio verbo *ser* un participio de presente, en contraposición al participio de pasado *sido*? ¿O esto que pregunto no tiene sentido?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como le he comentado a Gustavson, barajaba la posibilidad de que el participio de presente (o activo) del verbo *ser* fuera *ente*. Y buscando un poco he dado con un artículo de la Fundéu [que dice](https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/presidenta/):

> **El participio activo del verbo *ser* no es *ente*.** El único participio que actualmente tienen, de forma general, los verbos españoles, es el de perfecto (por ejemplo *sido*, para el verbo *ser*, o *comido* para *comer*). Solo algunos verbos tienen entre sus derivados los llamados participios activos, que hoy se consideran sustantivos (como *presidente*) o adjetivos (como *atacante* o *cantante*). El verbo *ser* tuvo en el pasado una forma de participio activo hoy perdida, pero no era *ente* sino *eseyente*.

Buscando en el diccionario, vemos que efectivamente la forma existe:

> **[eseyente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GOvaLA2)**
>
> `De`*`eser`*`y`*`-nte.`*
>
> 1. adj. desus. Que es.

La forma provendría del antiguo verbo *[eser](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GOu4akS)*, pero no encuentro ejemplos de uso en el CORDE. Lo que sí veo es que la RAE lo registra desde 1791, y ya entonces estaba marcado como "antiguo".

Tras buscar un poco, gracias a Ngram he encontrado algún que otro texto que usa la voz *eseyente*. [Cito uno](https://books.google.es/books?id=9JM3AQAAIAAJ&q=%22eseyente%22&dq=%22eseyente%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv66rrq4njAhUO-hQKHcd6DPoQ6AEINDAD):

> *Otra vez, la oposición entre el sistema y la realidad-válvula, entre lo eseyente lo eseíble; la excepción, confirma la regla.*
>
> Revista jurídica argentina "La Ley", volumen 75, página 213 (1954).

Personalmente me ha gustado el juego de palabras *entre lo eseyente y lo eseíble*: "entre lo que es y lo que puede ser".

Answer (score 3):

El único adjetivo posible es "existente". En una nota al pie en páginas 106 y 107 de la Gramática General de Antoine Louis Destutt, Conde de Tracy (1822), el traductor al español decía:

> (a) Por una singularidad no fácil de explicar, el verbo *ser*, el único que contiene por su significación propia la idea de la existencia, carece en castellano y en casi todas las lenguas de participio activo, o de forma adjetiva; por  lo tanto me veo precisado de valerme del gerundio *siendo* para expresar lo que diría, si existiese, el adjetivo *siente*, [...]

[image: Nota al pie p.106]
[image: Nota al pie p.107]

Comment: Pues yo estaba sopesando la idea de que el participio de presente del verbo _ser_ era _[ente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FgPanvT)_. Qué interesantes son siempre las singularidades...