# ¿Cuándo se usó el verbo "eser"? ¿Cómo se conjugaba?

Tags: verbos, historia, conjugación, cópulas

En la pregunta *[¿Tiene o ha tenido el verbo "ser" participio de presente?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30817/12637)* hemos descubierto una forma antigua del verbo *ser*:

> **[eser](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GOu4akS)**
>
> Del lat. **essĕre*, de *esse* 'ser<sup>1</sup>'.
>
> 1. copulat. desus. **ser<sup>1</sup>**. Era u. t. c. aux. e intr.

Buscando en diccionarios antiguos, su primer registro se encuentra en el diccionario español-inglés de Stevens de 1706:

> *Eser*, Obs. for *Ser*, to be.

Es decir, ya a principios del siglo XVIII estaba marcado como obsoleto. La misma marca de "antiguo" le da el *Academia usual* de 1791, su primera aparición por parte de la RAE.

Si buscamos *eser* en el CORDE salen 479 casos, pero solo en 16 documentos. Es decir, que en realidad son muy pocos los autores que usaron esta forma. De hecho, 457 casos son de un libro de 1419, copia de una traducción de Pedro de Toledo (traductor del siglo XII) de la *Guía de los Perplejos*, de Maimónides.

Luego pregunto: ¿En qué época se usó el verbo *eser*? ¿Tuvo un uso mayoritario o restringido? Y lo que más me intriga: ¿cómo se conjugaba?

Comment: En catalá, las dos formas del infinitivo *ser* y *ésser* se conjugan de la misma manera (pero hay multiplicidad en los participios *essent/sent* y *estat/sigut/set*).

Comment: Lo que dice @jacobo es cierto, se sigue usando en catalán pero en castellano se abandonó su uso a finales del s XVII, debido a que evolucionó a "ser"

Comment: And *ser* used to be *seer*: Del lat. sedēre 'estar sentado'. 

1. copulat. desus. ser. Era u. t. c. aux. e intr

Comment: Estaba leyendo sobre el español neomexicano, y por lo visto se usa allá desinencias antiguas del verbo *ser*: *yo* ***seigo***; *nosotros* ***semos***.

Answer (score 1):

El empleo del verbo “eser” 'ser' se encuentra registrado desde 1411 en los “Archivos Municipales de Huesca” y en un documento de 1596 del monasterio de san Victoriano de la villa de Graus (Huesca).

*Las formas del verbo „ser“ en castellano resultan de la fusión de dos verbos latinos ESSE y SEDERE. La mayor parte proceden de ESSE; sólo el futuro y condicional, los presentes de subjuntivo e imperativo y las formas impersonales proceden de SEDERE ‘estar sentado’, que en castellano debilitó su significado hasta convertirse en sinónimo de „estar“ y luego „ser“*.

*Todavía en el siglo XIII se distinguían „seer“ y „ser“, „seer“ con el sentido de ‘estar ahí’, ‘permanecer’, formando un eje: seer, estar/ser*.

*En el verbo „ser“ se fundieron los vebos ESSE y SEDERE. El infinitivo de ser no procede de ESSE sino de SEDERE*:

*sedere > se(d)ere > seer > ser*

*Puesto que el verbo ESSE no tenía gerundio, se tomó SEDERE para el gerundio*:

*sedendum > sediendo > seyendo > siendo
Las formas procedentes de SEDERE llevaban necesariamente una idea de situación, es decir, determinaban el existir en un determinado lugar.
Las formas procedentes de ESSE eran más abstractas, el existir no conllevaba necesariamente determinación espacial. En un principio predominaron las formas de ESSE y después las de SEDERE, hasta que finalmente las formas de SEDERE se oscurecieron y muchas se perdieron por el crecimiento avasallador de „estar“, verbo que tiene un sentido de ‘existir’ en un determinado espacio*.“

(Urrutia Cárdenas, H. / Álvarez Álvarez, M.: Esquema de morfosintaxis histórica del español. Bilbao: Universidad de Deusto, ²1988, pp. 234, 242,320)

---

Dada la fragilidad en esos tiempos de una solidez para establecer, como lo hacemos en la actualidad, de los nombres y tiempos verbales y sus distintas voces que difieren en los distintas localizaciones de España, te dejo una página donde puedes ampliar esos conocimientos más pausadamente, ya que es un tema para profundizar pues parece que existe una horquilla que va desde el 950 hasta el 1400 en donde los términos van evolucionando, abajo al final podrás ver toda una serie de formaciones y el número que de éstas se han encontrado que te ayuda a seguir analizando la cuestión.

http://ghcl.ub.edu/diccaxv/dictionary/ViewLema/19430

P.D. Respecto al  participio de presente. *Cuando en Filosofía se estudia el ser y lo "eseyente", "Lo que es’, según el Diccionario de la Academia. La palabra derivada eseyente es lo que en gramática española se llama participio activo, que actualiza o manifiesta al actor o agente de la idea expresada en la raíz del verbo; así de ayudar sale ayudante y de florecer floreciente. Eseyente proviene del antiguo verbo eser (del lat. essěre); y como hoy la lengua tiene ser en vez de eser, correspondería usar seyente por eseyente*.

---

El Presente quedaría;

Yo    - so/seo, según la localización

Tu    - - eres - del castellano antiguo eres ("eres"), del latín eris ("serás").

El    - eris ( es ("eres") y est ("es") se volvieron homófonos, igualmente se comenzó a usar como presente la forma del futuro imperfecto, "eris" ("serás"), con la pequeña variante que lo distinguía de "eres", con objeto de evitar confusiones ya que en ese momento dejaba de ser usada como futuro.

Nos   - Somos

Vos   - Sois/seis, según localización

Ellos - S0n